# @apollo_client.js?v=dbeae2a1:78 Uncaught Error: Could not resolve "react" imported by "rehackt". Is it installed?

Tags: reactjs, vuejs3, vite

While using apollo client in vite, I get the error `@apollo_client.js?v=dbeae2a1:78 Uncaught Error: Could not resolve "react" imported by "rehackt". Is it installed?` in the console even though I want the library without react (vanilla javascript)? I imported ApolloClient from `@apollo/client/core` My main.js:

```
//src/main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import { ApolloClient, gql, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client/core';
import { DefaultApolloClient } from '@vue/apollo-composable';
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router';
import Post from '@/components/Post.vue';
import Author from '@/components/Author.vue';
import PostsByTag from '@/components/PostsByTag.vue';
import AllPosts from '@/components/AllPosts.vue';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: 'https://localhost:8000/graphql',
});

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    link: httpLink,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
const routes = [
  { path: '/author/:username', component: Author },
  { path: '/post/:slug', component: Post },
  { path: '/tag/:tag', component: PostsByTag },
  { path: '/', component: AllPosts },
];
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHashHistory(),
    routes: routes,
});

const app = createApp(App);

app.provide(DefaultApolloClient, apolloClient);

app.mount('#app');
```

Comment: what version of **apollo_client** you are using

Comment: @apollo/client@3.9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well,  **apollo_client**  requires `react` even if you don't use react at all. It's a peer dependency.

Comment: Adding react didn't resolve the problem

Comment: try deleting  **node_modules** folder and execute `npm install`  than `npm cache clean` to make sure there is no cached dependencies . be aware that the you might get a new versions of your dependencies.  if you want to keep the same old version for some reason

Comment: There are two node_modules, one in project root (VueProject) and another at VueProject/frontend. Which one should I delete?

Comment: The one in your project root  ( vue0roject)